# Accessing/Changing UI Element Properties from a different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of a Dispatcher Object in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159015/what-is-the-use-of-a-dispatcher-object-in-wpf)

Sorry to ask what appears to be a fairly common question, but I've got a problem with threads trying to access UI objects and failing because "a different thread owns them".

I've read around and there's a lot out there on this, but I've been unable to find anything specific that helps me and I'm too new to threads and threading to be able to understand the answers and extract the knowledge I need from the sources I have found.

What I have in my code at the moment is this:

```
    void Sc_OnDataSetFilled()
    {
        ddlSelectGraph.SelectedIndex = 0;

        this.DataContext = App.Sc.PepperOverview;
    }
```

It's an event handler, which is triggered elsewhere in the code when a `DataSet` is successfully populated. When this is done, I want the `SelectedIndex` of the `ComboBox` `ddlSelectGraph` to change, which is where the code trips up because of the UI element belonging to a different thread.

This same issue occurs when the debugger tries to set the page's `DataContext` property, because that `DataSource` I talked about earlier is part of the other thread as well.

Could someone please give me some idiot proof advice, or point me towards some please?

Comment: You use the Dispatcher to marshall a call to the UI thread.  Each thread has its own Dispatcher, so you have to get a reference to the one that belongs to the UI thread.  There is no "idiot proof" advice to be given when it comes to multithreading.  Other than "don't do it", that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<object>((context) => 
                {
                    this.DataContext = context; // your implementation goes here
                }), 
                new object[1] 
                { 
                    "you object" // the object(s) you'd like to pass in
                });
```